# Git merge with lost history

Tags: git

I've developed a feature on a branch.  During the development, we moved to a different git host, and some of the commits were merged onto the new host.  I'm now trying to merge the rest back, and having problems.  The history looks like this:

```
  B------E-----G             | feature branch
 /        \     \
A----C     \     \           | master
      \     \     \
       D-----F-----H         | new master
```

At F, a squashed patch of changes (B:E) was applied to new master, so there's no history.  I want to make the G->H merge, but am getting conflicts when I do so.

What's the best way to effect this merge, ideally retaining history for the new changes between E and G?

Comment: "a patch was applied" : do you mean there is a commit `F--F'--H` ?

Comment: @LeGEC - Question updated to be clearer.

Comment: You might get a cleaner apply if you `git checkout -b wip newmaster; git reset --hard D; git merge E; git merge feature`, i.e. redo it but without the squash.  If that does it cleanly, then you can `git checkout -B newmaster` if you don't mind clients having to rebase or do a `git checkout newmaster; git merge -Xtheirs wip` otherwise.  Of course, if the initial `git merge E` still gives conflicts you might prefer to just do (only) `git merge -Xtheirs feature` directly on newmaster and then check the results very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is : solve the conflicts.

If `E----G` is a succession of commits, you can try to merge them one by one on top of `F` - this should give you a way to handle the the conflicts one spoonful at a time. After that, you will have ways to play with the history to end up with one single merge commit on top of `F`.

From what you describe : `F` is a merge commit of the feature branch on top of new master. The history is not lost : it is a mix of `B--F` and `C--F`.

This merge may have produced conflicts, which were solved before comitting. The differences between `E` and `F` are the places which can yield conflicts when you try to merge `G` and `F`.

You can see those differences with : `git diff E F`